# How to use variables in getRange in a macro, Copy range of rows to an other Google sheet with varible destination

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to make a macro, where I want to copy data from one sheet, and paste into an other sheet, where the destination cell range is variable. I have the variable destination in a cell. My question is: How to use variables in getRange()?

Comment: In what format is your destination?

Comment: Please provide more context. What does the variable destination in your cell look like? A1-- Notation? Column-row notation?

Answer (score 0):

It depend of you destinaton format in your variable.

If you have something like "A1:B3" use [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
Example:

```
var values = yourCopiedSheet.getRange("A1:C3").getValues()
var destiation = yourTargetSheet.getRange("A1").getValue()
yourTargetSheet.getRange(destination).setValues(values)
```

If you have an other format of notation, you will have to parse it so the value can fit in [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: Hi, thx for answering. I need to assign a function to  a button. Function must copy A1:C3 in active sheet, and then copy data to mynewsheet! where destination row is calculated in a cell in active sheet. The finally delete initial cells A1:C3.

Comment: How destination is writed in the cell once calculated?

Comment: It is written: mysheet!$A$1. I thinnk my problem is that can't get destination data in cell in sheet transform to a var in the script. (Yes I am a newbe to this)

Comment: to transform int a var just use `var destiation = yourTargetSheet.getRange("A1").getValue()`, as show bellow. Then you will have to eigther to change the notation format in your sheet or parse the value in you script using functions like split() or slice().